# E-commerce: How to update the price of an item in an existing purchase

Tags: e-commerce, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I have implemented E-commerce with Measurement Protocol for Google Analytics 4.

It works fine.

But I can't find out how I can update product price in an existing purchase.

For example, the user bought a book.

Its price is $10.

So my system sent a "purchase" event to ga4.

```
[
  'client_id' => 'xxxx',
  'events'    => [
    'name'   => 'purchase',
    'params' => [
        'transaction_id' => 'T-123',
         'currency'      => 'USD',
         'value'         => 10.00,
          ...
         'items'         => [
             [
                 'currency' => 'USD',
                 'price'    => 10.00,
                 ...
            ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

After 5 minutes, the user informed that he has a 10% coupon.

That is, he will pay $9 instead of $10.

How can I update data of existing purchase?

I first tried to refund this purchase using the refund event

```
[
  'client_id' => 'xxxx',
  'events'    => [
    'name'   => 'refund',
    'params' => [
        'transaction_id' => 'T-123',
         'value'         => 10.00,
          ...
         'items'         => [
             [
                 'price' => 10.00,
                 ...
            ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

(^ it works ok)

and then send the purchase event again with the updated data

```
[
  'client_id' => 'xxxx',
  'events'    => [
    'name'   => 'purchase',
    'params' => [
        'transaction_id' => 'T-123',
         'value'         => 9.00,
          ...
         'items'         => [
             [
                 'price' => 9.00,
                 ...
            ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

But my second purchase event is being ignored.

I can't find this data in ga4.

**Note.** I use the same parameter "transaction_id" = "T-123".

Because I don't want to create a new purchase.

I just want to update an existing purchase.

How can this be implemented?